# Unitarity of CKM matrix?

Tags: standard-model, quarks

The [CKM matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix) is known to be unitary.

Now, is it just found experimentally?

Is the following idea correct?

We know that the weak force eigenstate
$  \left( \begin{array}{c}
d' \\
s' \\
b' \end{array} \right) $ are related to the physical state
$  \left( \begin{array}{c}
d \\
s  \\
b \end{array} \right)  $  via the Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa (CKM) matrix :
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c}
d' \\
s' \\
b' \end{array} \right) = V_{CKM}\left( \begin{array}{c}
d \\
s \\
b \end{array} \right)$$

Orthogonality of the weak force eigenstates AND of the physical states dictates that:
$$
( d' 
s' 
b' )
\left( \begin{array}{c}
d' \\
s' \\
b' \end{array} \right)
=
( d 
s 
b )
\left( \begin{array}{c}
d \\
s \\
b \end{array} \right) = 1 $$

SO:

$$1 = ( d' 
s' 
b' )
\left( \begin{array}{c}
d' \\
s' \\
b' \end{array} \right) = V_{CKM}^{\dagger} V_{CMK} ( d 
s 
b )
\left( \begin{array}{c}
d \\
s \\
b \end{array} \right) = V_{CKM}^{\dagger} V_{CMK}$$

Therefore $V_{CKM}^{\dagger} V_{CMK} = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last equation does not make sense. On the left had side you have a scalar 1, while on the right hand side there is supposed to be the unit matrix. However, it is
$$
1=\begin{pmatrix}d' & s' & b'\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}d' \\ s' \\ b'\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}d & s & b\end{pmatrix}V_{CKM}^\dagger V_{CKM}\begin{pmatrix}d \\ s \\ b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now, since the $\begin{pmatrix}d \\ s \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ form an orthonormal basis, $V_{CKM}^\dagger V_{CKM}$ has to be the unit matrix. In general, if for an orthonormal basis $\{v_i\}$ of a vector space $V$, there is a Matrix $M$ such that
$$v_i^\dagger M v_i =1$$ for all $i$, then $M$ must be the unit matrix.

In general, a change of bases between two orthonormal bases is always unitary.